# Curious behavior with Pyspark's repartition() (Dataframe API)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Let's say I have the following Pyspark dataframe:

```
data_df = (
    spark
    .createDataFrame(
        [
            [0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,2],[0,2,1],[0,0,2],[0,1,0],[0,20,21],[0,23,20],[0,21,25],[0,22,22],
            [1,100,102],[1,105,101],[1,102,102],[1,103,100],[1,1000,1000],[1,1001,1005],[1,1002,1001]
        ]
    )
)
```

I can show it:

```
+---+----+----+
| _1|  _2|  _3|
+---+----+----+
|  0|  20|  21|
|  1|1001|1005|
|  0|   0|   2|
|  1| 103| 100|
|  0|  23|  20|
|  1|1002|1001|
|  0|   0|   0|
|  0|  22|  22|
|  0|   0|   1|
|  0|   1|   0|
|  1| 100| 102|
|  1|1000|1000|
|  0|   1|   2|
|  1| 105| 101|
|  0|   2|   1|
|  1| 102| 102|
|  0|  21|  25|
+---+----+----+
```

Now, I ask for a repartition:

```
rep_data_df = (
    data_df
    .repartition(2, "_1")
)
```

As I understand it, that will create 2 partitions, being the data distributed according to the value of the first column.

Nevertheless, if I print the number of partitions and the partitions structure, this is the result:

```
print("Number of partitions: {}".format(rep_data_df.rdd.getNumPartitions()))
print("Partitions structure: {}".format(rep_data_df.rdd.glom().collect()))

Number of partitions: 2
Partitions structure: [[], [Row(_1=0, _2=21, _3=25), Row(_1=0, _2=2, _3=1), Row(_1=1, _2=102, _3=102), Row(_1=0, _2=23, _3=20), Row(_1=1, _2=1002, _3=1001), Row(_1=0, _2=0, _3=2), Row(_1=1, _2=103, _3=100), Row(_1=0, _2=0, _3=0), Row(_1=0, _2=22, _3=22), Row(_1=0, _2=20, _3=21), Row(_1=1, _2=1001, _3=1005), Row(_1=0, _2=1, _3=2), Row(_1=1, _2=105, _3=101), Row(_1=0, _2=0, _3=1), Row(_1=1, _2=100, _3=102), Row(_1=0, _2=1, _3=0), Row(_1=1, _2=1000, _3=1000)]]
```

As you can see, there are 2 partitions, that's OK, but the data was not partitioned as I expected: all the data is within a single partition, while the other one is empty.

More curious, if I ask for 3 partitions:

```
Number of partitions: 3
Partitions structure: [[], [Row(_1=0, _2=1, _3=2), Row(_1=0, _2=1, _3=0), Row(_1=0, _2=0, _3=2), Row(_1=0, _2=2, _3=1), Row(_1=0, _2=23, _3=20), Row(_1=0, _2=21, _3=25), Row(_1=0, _2=0, _3=0), Row(_1=0, _2=22, _3=22), Row(_1=0, _2=0, _3=1), Row(_1=0, _2=20, _3=21)], [Row(_1=1, _2=105, _3=101), Row(_1=1, _2=1000, _3=1000), Row(_1=1, _2=102, _3=102), Row(_1=1, _2=100, _3=102), Row(_1=1, _2=103, _3=100), Row(_1=1, _2=1001, _3=1005), Row(_1=1, _2=1002, _3=1001)]]
```

I.e. I get an empty partition and 2 other partitions with the expected distribution of the data.

Am I doing something wrong? Can anybody explain this behavior?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

Extremely curious! If I a replace all the occurrences of `0` in the first column with `2`, everything works as I expected!

```
data_df = (
    spark
    .createDataFrame(
        [
            [2,0,0],[2,0,1],[2,1,2],[2,2,1],[2,0,2],[2,1,0],[2,20,21],[2,23,20],[2,21,25],[2,22,22],
            [1,100,102],[1,105,101],[1,102,102],[1,103,100],[1,1000,1000],[1,1001,1005],[1,1002,1001]
        ]
    )
)
```

Showing it:

```
+---+----+----+
| _1|  _2|  _3|
+---+----+----+
|  2|   2|   1|
|  2|  23|  20|
|  2|  20|  21|
|  2|   0|   0|
|  2|  21|  25|
|  2|   0|   2|
|  2|   1|   0|
|  2|   0|   1|
|  2|  22|  22|
|  2|   1|   2|
|  1| 100| 102|
|  1|1000|1000|
|  1|1001|1005|
|  1|1002|1001|
|  1| 105| 101|
|  1| 103| 100|
|  1| 102| 102|
+---+----+----+
```

Then asking for repartition and checking the partitions:

```
Number of partitions: 2
Partitions structure: [[Row(_1=2, _2=22, _3=22), Row(_1=2, _2=1, _3=0), Row(_1=2, _2=0, _3=2), Row(_1=2, _2=2, _3=1), Row(_1=2, _2=0, _3=0), Row(_1=2, _2=20, _3=21), Row(_1=2, _2=0, _3=1), Row(_1=2, _2=21, _3=25), Row(_1=2, _2=1, _3=2), Row(_1=2, _2=23, _3=20)], [Row(_1=1, _2=100, _3=102), Row(_1=1, _2=105, _3=101), Row(_1=1, _2=1001, _3=1005), Row(_1=1, _2=1002, _3=1001), Row(_1=1, _2=103, _3=100), Row(_1=1, _2=102, _3=102), Row(_1=1, _2=1000, _3=1000)]]
```

What is wrong with the value `0`? xD

Is this a bug?